# Spring Boot 3 Authorization server config for token generation with TokenStore

Tags: access-token, spring-authorization-server, spring-boot-3, spring-security-6

I'm trying to create an oAuth-service using spring security in spring boot 3.2 during the integration of spring security. However, while developing, I discovered several classes that are "Deprecated" (such as AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter and TokenStore, although they are compatible with spring boot 2); as a result, can anyone provide a solution, documentation, or tutorial?

Actually, I'm hoping for an auth-service based on auth2 tokens, not JWT.

Could you also tell me if the spring security approach from spring boot 2 can be used to spring boot 3 or if spring boot 3 has replaced it?

Answer (score 0):

The Spring Security OAuth has [reached end of life](https://spring.io/blog/2022/06/01/spring-security-oauth-reaches-end-of-life/) and is replaced by the [Spring Authorization Server](https://spring.io/projects/spring-authorization-server/) project, which is based on Spring Framework 6 and compatible with Spring Boot 3 as of the 1.0 release in November 2022.